# Trouble having Dual-booting windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

First of all I'm completely new to ubuntu.
First I downloaded the Ubuntu 15.4 iso and copied into a flashdrive and made it bootable.
Then after entering the setup, I couldn't find the option to install ubuntu along with windows, 
So I've decided to create a partition manually. (As I've mentioned earlier, I'm completely new to this).
I had **18 gb** unallocated space.. first I created the swap with 6gb and created root with remaining space. Then the installation was completed sucessfully. 
but when I clicked restart, There wasn't any screen to select the os to boot, the system boot normally into windows, when I checked advanced system settings > startup and recovery, there wasn't any other os installed.
But when I checked, a ext4 partition and swap partition was present.
What was the wrong ?
How can I dualboot properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey bud here are some step by step instructions http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/07/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-15-04-with-windows-10-on-a-single-hard-drive/